# Android Studio - IceCreamSandwich remains "Partially installed"

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to develop an app targeting the API 15. However every time I try to install the SDK platform in Android Studio, it stop before the end,showing connection timed out, and leave me with a partially installed SDK platform...

Trying it several times with the rights and a good internet connection gave the same result every time. I can still compile and (sometimes...) run my app using it but some bugs are there as well and since I'm pretty sure it's linked, I would lik to get the platform properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Go to Android sdk manager which shows the “Partially installed” below that there is an option called launch standalone sdk manager click that and check all the required sdk is install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a country like China where Google is blocked or where you might have any problem with `https`, this fix the problem:

Check "Force https://... " (to force SDK Manager to use http instead of https)

For the rest the problem can come from the server as well.

Answer (score 4):

Using Android Studio version 2.3.3, to check which components of the SDK package for the platform were not installed properly:

1. Start the Android Studio **"SDK Manager"**
2. Under the **"SDK Platforms"** tab, select the check-box at the bottom that says **"Show Package Details"**
3. The SDK package will be expanded and show you the status ("Installed", "Not Installed", "Partially Installed") for **each component** of the package

This will enable you to install the components individually, and if they fail to install, debug what the issue is.